# why input has class , id and name ? can i use class or id as tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to know more about the form tag
like what is `for="name"` in the label
why input has id or class?

```
<body><form action="/action_page.php">

    <label for="name">Name</label><br>

    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required><br>


    <label for="email">Email</label><br>

    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email address" required>

<br>
    <label for="age">Age (Optional)</label><br>

    <input type="number" id="age" name="age-number" placeholder="Age" max="99" min="10" required>

<br>
    <label for="role">Which option best describes your current role?</label><br>

    <select id="role" name="role" required >

        <option disabled selected value>Select current role</option>

        <option value="student">Student</option>

        <option value="job">Full Time Job</option>

        <option value="learner">Full Time Learner</option>

        <option value="preferNo">Prefer not to say</option>

        <option value="other">Other</option>

      </select>
</body
```

Answer (score 0):

**for**

When used together with the `<label>` element, the `for` attribute specifies which form element a label is bound to.

**id**

The HTML `id` attribute is used to specify a unique id for an HTML element. You cannot have more than one element with the same `id` in an HTML document.

**class**

The HTML `class` attribute is used to specify a class for an HTML element.
Multiple HTML elements can share the same class.

Read more here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_for.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

Comment: thanks, so you mean if I  specify a class or id in the input. will I be able to use increase font size or others CSS? I also have a question that why name attribute is used in the input?

Comment: you can find out more about name attribute here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp and yes, you can increase font size or other CSS by specifying the id or class in the css like these: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp